# Reduce white noise when using navigator.webkitGetUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, getusermedia

Hi I'm using the navigator.webkitGetUserMedia in order to stream my pc video and audio

the problem is when the audio is streaming from the laptop or phone built-in mic .
I get a lot of white noise and barely can hear myself. 
I search for this issue online and found couple of questions here but they are old (2010, 2013 ... ) and I wondering if anyone came across this issue and succeed to solve it.

I'm using chrome Version 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit) 
I have tried to use the audio optional flags but with no help

Thanks for all the helpers !!!:)

here is my input code:

```
function setMediaDevice() {


    navigator.getUserMedia = (
        navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia
    );
    if (navigator.getUserMedia){
        navigator.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
              audio: true
                }

        }, function(myStream) {

            localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(myStream);

        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    else{
    alert("failed to load user input")
    }

}
```

Comment: I would've thought that's down to the microphone - what's wrong with the old questions? microphones haven't changed that much in 5 years

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with your code, nor something you should try to solve with code.  You have either a poorly configured audio input or a bad microphone.  If you try to fix this with code, you're going to ruin the audio quality for everyone else with proper working hardware.

Check your audio config, make sure the microphone pre-amp is on.  Make sure the levels are set appropriately.  Get the dust and lint out of your microphone.  Make sure the cooling fan isn't blowing into it.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your response but I must say I disagree with you.
each device make a noise (phones, laptops, TV etc.) 
The issue with the white noise is related to the device noise that the built-in microphone get. 
This issue occurs not only my laptop, but on other laptops and smart phones.

Comment: @ShalomBalulu You're wrong.  And, if you cared to test with a loopback driver to isolate your problem, you can prove to yourself that you're wrong.  But of course, do whatever you want... it's your code, your application, and your responsibility.